# So i am trying to make a death/respawn thing in my game i am using a character collider but it doesnt work help pls

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a easy script that detected collision but only respawned me when i was jumping or falling on the "dangerous" object if i walked into it nothing happend then i changed the script and i dont get repawned at all help please

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public CharacterController controller;

  private MeshCollider mesh;
   
   public float speed = 12f;
   public float gravity = -9.81f;
   public float jumpHeight = 3f;

   public Transform groundCheck;
   public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
   public LayerMask groundMask;

   Vector3 velocity;
   bool isGrounded;

   [SerializeField] 
   private Transform respawnPoint;

   [SerializeField]
   private Transform player;
    
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }



    void Update()
    {
       

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0 )
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }


        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision hit)
    
            //collision detecting system
   
    {
        if(hit.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle"){
            Debug.Log("We hit" + hit.gameObject.name);
        player.transform.position = respawnPoint.transform.position;
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

the other script was somethig like this:

[image]

I am making a parkour game btw and trying to make some logs that spin and if you thoutch them you restart

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is not clear what is your problem. No respawn? No collision detection? No collision dection when failing on an object? What is the first and what is the second version of the script you posted? Explain what is the expected behavior, what did you try, what did not work.

Comment: first is the photo

Comment: and the second is from the bigger script the last few lines

Comment: it does not respawn me when i walk into the object but when i fall on it it does respawn me the expected behaviour is whenever i thoutch the object in every way it respawns me

Comment: the thing is that it detects the ground below me not the frontal collision that is the explanation

Comment: and i want it to detect collisions in every way

Answer (score 0):

a) You're better off using `OnTriggerEnter` for what you're trying to achieve here.

b) If you're using a mesh collider, it's a good idea to have `isConvex` checked. it helps simplify your collisions

c) **You might want to look at how your colliders are set up on the character**, if they have multiple colliders for different body parts. **It could be that you may have multiple colliders, but only one of them has a rigidbody attached, the others dont.** This will cause the collision events to not fire at all on the other colliders.